# SWT and full disabling and hide mouse pointer

Tags: java, events, cursor, swt, hide

I need some help to hide and disabling mouse pointer. But I need to send all mouse events to an other device.
So main scenario is: open SWT application --> press button (or label, or what you want...) --> disappearing mouse SWT-side, no pointer, no event --> mouse pointer appear in other device --> I can control other device's mouse pointer from main physically mouse.

What I found by now is how to make pointer transparent and I thought about timer that could fix location each 20ms. But how can I prevent events? And can I still catch them?

Regards

Update:

Final solution: new full-screen window semi-transparent

```
public class AntiMouseGui {

    Display display;
    Shell shell;

    final int time = 20;

    private Runnable timer = null;

    public AntiMouseGui(final Display display, final DebugForm df, final PrintWriter socketOut) {

        Image bg = new Image(display, "icons/hide_mouse_wallpapaer.png");

        shell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP);

        final int dis_x = display.getClientArea().width, dis_y = display.getClientArea().height;
        shell.setSize(dis_x, dis_y);

        shell.setBackgroundImage(bg);
        shell.setAlpha(50);
        shell.setMinimumSize(shell.getSize()); 
        shell.open();


        timer = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Point cur_loc = display.getCursorLocation();
                int span_x = dis_x / 2 - cur_loc.x, span_y = dis_y / 2 - cur_loc.y;

                df.appendTxt("span x = " + span_x + " span y = " + span_y);
                if (span_x != 0) Controller.moveMouseRight(socketOut, -span_x);
                if (span_y != 0) Controller.moveMouseDown(socketOut, -span_y);

                display.setCursorLocation(new Point(dis_x / 2, dis_y / 2));
                if (!shell.isDisposed()) display.timerExec(time, this);
            }
        };
        display.timerExec(time, timer);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate. It's hard to tell what exactly is being asked here.

Comment: What I mean is I need catch mouse events and send them to an other device

Comment: Catch them from where and send them where?

Comment: Catch from desktop-side and send to Android-side. And I need no effect for event in desktop-side.

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about android. How are the applications connected, i.e. how can the SWT part and the android part communicate?

Comment: I didn't say anything about that because it's not important. My question is only SWT-side. What I need is catch events, prevent effect SWT-side. When I know what user's mouse is doing I can easily send event to android using my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Shell` that is full screen and set it's alpha value to 0. Then just add a `Listener` to the `Display` and catch all the mouse events:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    shell.setFullScreen(true);
    shell.setAlpha(0);

    final Listener sendSomewhere = new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            int x = event.x;
            int y = event.y;

            int eventType = event.type;

            System.out.println(x + " " + y + ": " + eventType);

            // send the coordinates to your other device
        }
    };

    int[] events = new int[] {SWT.MouseDown, SWT.MouseUp, SWT.MouseDoubleClick, SWT.Selection};

    for(int event : events)
    {
        display.addFilter(event, sendSomewhere);
    }


    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Just use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get back to your previous window.

Comment: This code prevent catching only in SWT. But I need a "remote control style", in witch you can't do anything in local. Something like this: http://synergy-foss.org/

Comment: @user1417608 This cannot be done with Java, because Java can only control stuff within the window. Maybe it's possible with JNI.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution opening a full-screen transparent window. Could works if I reach transparent feature.

Comment: @user1417608 See edited answer. Please try to add as much relevant detail to your questions as possible. Then I would have been able to help you more quickly.